# Can't unlock screen after changing password

Tags: lock-screens, locked-out

So one night i was using my Galaxy Tab A and realized that someone had taken my screen lock off, so every time I had opened my screen cover it would just automatically unlock my screen. So I decided to put a lock back on it and the password type that I was using previously was the "Direction swipes" lock and the combination I thought was just way too easy, and I really liked this type of screen lock. So I came up with an even harder combination and after awhile I had pressed the power button to lock the screen, and when I tried turning it back on I didn't even swipe up on the screen to unlock it and instantly realized I had already forgotten the new combination. So I've been using the guest user on my tablet.

So my question is, how do I get back into the main users screen without having to factory reset the whole device? Is there any chance of that?

Please help me somebody, anybody!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check this link, for solved you not need enable debuging and root:

[Why does Android Device Manager not changes my password?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/207287/why-does-android-device-manager-not-changes-my-password/207299#207299)