# Why does Android Device Manager not changes my password?

Tags: locked-out, android-device-manager

I have an Android phone with password, but I don't remember it. I have access to the phone through Android Device Manager. I tried to change the password with it, but when I set the new password, Android Device Manager says:

> The phone has a password, the password you just entered will not be used

How can I change the password? I have not logged in with Samsung and adb does not recognize the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by installing ClockworkMod, and Aroma file manager with a sdcard, then I removed the next files:

- password.keypattern.key
- locksettings.db
- locksettings.db-shm
- locksettings.db-wal

Useful links:

[HOW TO: Install ClockworkMod Recovery 6 on Galaxy S5 G900F](https://www.teamandroid.com/2014/04/12/install-galaxy-s5-g900f-g900h-clockworkmod-recovery-6-guide/2/)

[Remove /Bypass Lockscreen With Recovery](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/remove-lockscreen-recovery-t3530008)